# Fortran-Python linking

Tags: python, debugging, fortran

I am trying to convert a Fortran file to a python module using f2py. I have converted the .f file .o file where I have defined a subroutine called SDIVINI and UMAT. During the linking, I have instructed the f.90 file to call the subroutine from the converted .o file. However, it shows the undefined reference to SDIVINI and UMAT although both of the subroutines are defined inside the converted .o file. I get the following error in the dark background photo. I have used the following commands to call the file shown in the white background photo. I am using gfortran in windows.     [calling the UMAT from .o file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjyIf.jpg)[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6gEv.jpg)

Comment: If you are going to call the code from f90, why bother converting to python.  You only need to convert to python if you intend to use it in python.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I intend to use the fortran code as a module in python. For that reason I am using the f2py of numpy to covert the fortran file to python module.